# does there exist a countably infinite normed field which is complete?

Tags: p-adic-number-theory, valuation-theory

We know $Q$ with any of $p$ aidic norms is not complete for all primes including infinity. Now my question is can we make same conclusion for any countably infinite fields ? i.e does there exist a countably infinite normed linear field which is complete ?

Answer (score 2):

Such a field is a topological group, hence homogeneous. [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1380799/are-homogenous-countable-complete-metric-spaces-always-discrete) answer shows such a space must be discrete. Can you show normed fields cannot be discrete?

Answer (score 1):

For any field the trivial norm with $|0|=0$ and $|x|=1$ for nonzero $x$ is complete (because distinct points are at distance $1$ from each other, so any Cauchy sequence is eventually constant).

If the norm is not trivial, take an element $x$ with $|x|<1$ (replace with $1/x$ if necessary).  Then $|x^n|=|x|^n$, so $x^n$ converges to $0$.  So $0$ is not an isolated point and the space is not discrete.  Daron's answer now shows that such a field cannot be countably infinite if it is complete.